# Histogram of string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to find how many times letters appear in string. But I need to ignore the difference between lowercase and uppercase letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void stringHistogram(char *s) {
  int i, len = 0, counts[256] = {0};
  len = strlen(s);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    counts[(s[i])]++;
  }
  for (i = 65; i < 123; i++) {
      if(i>=91&&i<=96)continue;
    if (counts[i] > 0)
       printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", i, counts[i]);
  }
}
int main() {
  char s[] = "!!!!!PrOgraMMing -------iN C Is easy....";
  stringHistogram(s);

  return 0;
}
```

For example in this string "I" appears once and "i" appears twice. I want to add these two numbers and print number of them as one character. Program output should be "I appears 3 times."
Could you help me modify these code?

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` and `counts[toupper((unsigned char)s[i])]++;`

Comment: Make sure you index the `counts` array with an *unsigned* value.

Comment: Don't use magic values like `65` and `< 123`. Use `'A'` and `<= 'z'`

Comment: @Cheatah Better to use [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) or other [character classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) functions instead.

Comment: I actually agree. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Because of the way ASCII is set up, you could get away with 64 histogram slots to ignore case, `counts[(ch & 31) + ((ch & 64) >> 1)]++`, but this will fail on non-ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void stringHistogram(char *s) {

  size_t len = 0;
  size_t counts[256] = {0};

  len = strlen(s);

  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < len; ++ii) {
    size_t idx = (size_t)s[ii];
    if((idx > 64) && (idx < 91)){
      idx += 32;
    }
    counts[idx]++;
  }

  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < 255; ++ii) {
    if(0 != isprint((char)ii)){
      if (counts[ii] > 0){
        printf("%lu [%c] occurs %lu times.\n", ii, (char)ii, counts[ii]);
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "!!!!!PrOgraMMing -------iN C Is easy....";
  stringHistogram(s);

  return 0;
}
```

first like 0___________, I handled upper/lower case while counting, also I used size_t over int (it's an unsigned type)

My output is

```
32 [ ] occurs 4 times.
33 [!] occurs 5 times.
45 [-] occurs 7 times.
46 [.] occurs 4 times.
97 [a] occurs 2 times.
99 [c] occurs 1 times.
101 [e] occurs 1 times.
103 [g] occurs 2 times.
105 [i] occurs 3 times.
109 [m] occurs 2 times.
110 [n] occurs 2 times.
111 [o] occurs 1 times.
112 [p] occurs 1 times.
114 [r] occurs 2 times.
115 [s] occurs 2 times.
121 [y] occurs 1 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `strlen` and then iterate the string again. Use the correct type for sizes.

```
void stringHistogram(const char *s) 
{
    size_t counts[256] = {0};

    while(*s) counts[toupper((unsigned char)*s++)] += 1;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(counts) / sizeof(counts[0]); i++)
        if (counts[i] > 0)
            printf("%3zu (`%c`) occurs %zu times.\n", i, isprint((unsigned char)i) ? (char)i : '.', counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: please modify to print just histogram of letters

Comment: I get warning `implicit declaration of function ‘isprint’`  and `implicit declaration of function ‘toupper’`

Comment: While this is a neat shortliner, I think it's too obscure. To many instructions in one line. For clarity's sake, this should be expanded

Comment: i think that while statement is way too clever for a beginner c coder. It will read like a magic spell, not something they can learn from